# Disable the DVD eject button on a Thinkpad running Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, thinkpad

My Thinkpad T420 has a problem. It's just too sensitive. I just slightly touch it on the right side, and woosh, the DVD drive pops open. (I think this is called a *premature ejection* :)).

Is there a way to disable the eject button? I'm running Linux (Fedora 17).

Comment: This is not a exact duplicate. The question you refer ask how to disable the button on **Windows** and the answer is a program called LockCD on **Windows**. I'm running **Linux**, so the answer does not help me. I'll flag this for moderator attention to reopen it.

Comment: I was posting an answer but couldn't because this got locked. FWIW I don't think that is an exact dupe either. Here's what I was gonna post; will add as answer if this gets unlocked: You can try `cdctl -o` or `cdctl --lockdoor` ([cdctl website](http://cdctl.sourceforge.net)).

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, it did not work. `cdctl -o` expects a numeric argument. I tried 0 and 1, both do not lock the door. I also tried `eject -i 1 /dev/sr0` and `echo 1 > /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/lock` as root and manually sending a CDROM_LOCKDOOR ioctl to the device. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Hmm, cdctl generally works. Perhaps your laptop's drive does not support the lock function.

Answer (score 3):

*This is a repost of an answer I provided to my own identical question on the Unix & Linux site titled: [How can I disable the button of my CD/DVD drive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104791/how-can-i-disable-the-button-of-my-cd-dvd-drive).*

---

The problem is definitely caused by UDEV as you've guessed. The issue is this line that is in most UDEV files related to the cdrom drive.

#### Example

On Fedora 19 there is the following file, `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules`. In this file is the following line which is co-opting the eject button for CD/DVD devices.

```
ENV{DISK_EJECT_REQUEST}=="?*", RUN+="cdrom_id --eject-media $devnode", GOTO="cdrom_end"
```

You can work around the issue and disable UDEV's ability to co-opt the eject button by doing the following:

1. Make a copy of the file `60-cdrom_id.rules`

   ```
   $ sudo cp /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/.
   ```
2. Edit this copied version of the file and comment out the line containing the string, `DISK_EJECT_REQUEST`.

   ```
   $ sudoedit /etc/udev/rules.d/60-cdrom_id.rules
   ```
3. Save the file and the change should be noticeable immediately!

The above solution fixes the problem for both `eject` and `cdctl`. So now the following commands work as expected:

*lock the drive*

```
$ eject -i on /dev/sr0
eject: CD-Drive may NOT be ejected with device button

-or-

$ cdctl -o1
```

*unlock the drive*

```
$ eject -i off /dev/sr0
eject: CD-Drive may be ejected with device button

-or-

$ cdctl -o0
```